# How to represent any integer value in a string?

Tags: python, string, integer

I am trying to determine if a sub-string exists within a text document of repetitive formatting. I am looping through specific keywords, and trying to identify another word after it. The two words are always separated by an integer, of varying value. I basically want a way to represent that integer in the sub-string as any integer value at all, if possible at all.
Something like this:

```
substr = keyword +' '+ integer +' '+ word
teststr = "one two three keyword 24 word four five"
if substr in teststr:
    print("substr exists in teststr")
```

Alternatively, I can do a loop and check around the iterator:

```
for el in teststr():
    checkstr = keyword +' '+ el.isdigit +' '+ word
    if checkstr in teststr:
        print("yes")
```

Just wondering if anyone knows an elegant solution at the top of their head.

Comment: Use regular expressions. Any number of one or more digits is simple as`\d+`

Comment: `re.search("keyword [0-9]+ word", teststr)` I suppose?

Comment: or rather `re.search(r"\bkeyword \d+ word\b", teststr)` (`\b` stands for “boundary”)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Regular Expressions to capture that pattern. Here is a quick implementation of what you are looking for:

```
import re

sample = "one two three keyword 24 word four five, another test is here pick 12 me"

# (\w+) is a group to include a word, followed by a number (\d+), then another word
pattern = r"(\w+).(\d+).(\w+)"
result = re.findall(pattern, sample)

if result:
   print('yes')
```

Comment: Thanks, this did it.

the key was the Regular Expression \d+